# Verify an image exists at a URL when HEAD is not allowed

Tags: google-drive-api, dotnet-httpclient

Using `HttpClient` in C#, I'm trying to verify that an image exists at a given URL without downloading the actual image. These images can come from any publicly accessible address.  I've been using the `HEAD` HTTP verb which seems to work for many/most.  Google drive images are proving difficult.

Given a public share link like so:
`https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oCmOEJp0vk73uYhzDTr2QJeKZOkyIm6v/view?usp=sharing`
I can happily use `HEAD`, get a `200 OK` and it appears to be happy.  But, that's not the image.  It's a page where one can download the image.

With a bit of mucking around, you can change the URL to this to actually get at the image, which is what I really want to check:
`https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1oCmOEJp0vk73uYhzDTr2QJeKZOkyIm6v`

But, hitting that URL with `HEAD` results in a `405 MethodNotAllowed`
Luckily, if the URL truly doesn't exist, you get back a `404 NotFound`

So I'm stuck at the `405`. What is my next step (NOT using Google APIs) when `HEAD` is not allowed? I can't assume it's a valid image if it simply doesn't `404`.  I check the `Content-type` to verify it's an image, which has issues outside the scope of this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HttpClient` allows us to issue an http request where you can specify that you are interested about only the headers.

The trick is to pass an `HttpCompletionOption` [enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpcompletionoption) value to the `SendAsync` or any other `{HttpVerb}Async` method:

```
| Enum name           | Value | Description                                                                                                         |
|---------------------|-------|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| ResponseContentRead | 0     | The operation should complete after reading the entire response including the content.                              |
| ResponseHeadersRead | 1     | The operation should complete as soon as a response is available and headers are read. The content is not read yet. |
```

```cs
await client.GetAsync(targetUrlWhichDoesNotSupportHead, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
```

Here is an [in-depth article](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/using-httpcompletionoption-responseheadersread-to-improve-httpclient-performance-dotnet) that details how does this enum changes the behavior and performance of the `HttpClient`.

The related source code fragments:

- in case of [.NET Framework](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/net/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs#L433)
- in case of [.NET Core](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/abc525d0c2a5b0be09e4d7e4c1e67571afb77c80/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs#L520)

Answer (score 1):

Brilliant, Peter!  Thank you.

Here's my full method for anyone who may find it useful:

```cs
public async Task<bool> ImageExists(string urlOrPath)
{
    try
    {
        var uri = new Uri(urlOrPath);
        if (uri.IsFile)
        {
            if (File.Exists(urlOrPath)) return true;
            _logger.LogError($"Cannot find image: [{urlOrPath}]");
            return false;
        }

        using (var result = await Get(uri))
        {
            if (result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            {
                _logger.LogError($"Cannot find image: [{urlOrPath}]");
                return false;
            }
            if ((int)result.StatusCode >= 400)
            {
                _logger.LogError($"Error: {result.ReasonPhrase}. Image: [{urlOrPath}]");
                return false;
            }
            if (result.Content.Headers.ContentType == null)
            {
                _logger.LogError($"No 'ContentType' header returned.  Cannot validate image:[{urlOrPath}]");
                return false;
            }
            if(new[] { "image", "binary"}.All(v => !result.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType.SafeTrim().Contains(v)))
            {
                _logger.LogError($"'ContentType' {result.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType} is not an image. The Url may point to an HTML download page instead of an actual image:[{urlOrPath}]");
                return false;
            }
            var validTypes = new[] { "jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png", "bmp", "binary" }; 
            if(validTypes.All(v => !result.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType.SafeTrim().Contains(v)))
            {
                _logger.LogError($"'ContentType' {result.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType} is not a valid image. Only [{string.Join(", ", validTypes)}] accepted. Image:[{urlOrPath}]");
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _logger.LogError($"There was a problem checking the image: [{urlOrPath}] is not valid. Error: {e.Message}");
        return false;
    }
}
private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(Uri uri)
{
    var response = await _httpCli.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Head, uri));
    if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed) return response;

    return await _httpCli.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage() { RequestUri = uri }, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
}
```

Edit: added a `Get()` method which still uses `HEAD` and only uses `ResponseHeadersRead` if it encounters `MethodNotAllowed`. Using a live scenario I found it was much quicker. Not sure why.  YMMV